# HTML markup adding redundant <a> tags <divs>?

Tags: html, css

I would like to wrap a thumbnail element into an anchor tag so that the whole element is a clickable link. As far as I can see, my markup looks correct but when I view the page in the browser and inspect the element, several  tags are added.

My markup:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
 <a class="link" href="page.html">
  <div class="thumbnail">
   <img alt="200x360" src="img.png">
    <div class="caption">
     <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
 <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
 <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">category</a></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </a>
 </div>
```

What I am seeing in the element inspector:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
<a class="link" href="page.html"></a>

    <div class="thumbnail"> <a class="link" href="page.html">
            <img alt="200x360" src="img.png">
        </a>

        <div class="caption"><a class="link" href="page.html">
            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>
    </a>

            <p><a class="link" href="page.html"></a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">category</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been staring at my markup for 20 minutes and also shoved it through the validator. I'm not seeing any error. Anybody know what might be going on here?

Comment: "shoved it through the validator. I'm not seeing any error" Can we assume you're validating HTML5 then?

Comment: Does the extra markup appear in the source code when you do a view source?

Comment: It's because you're closing the `a.link` tag at the end. I don't know why this should happen, but the extra `a` tags would disappear if you put the closing `</a>` outside the `div.thumbnail`. See https://drupal.org/node/1868344

Comment: [Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A element must not contain any other A elements.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)

Comment: Thanks to Pranav and BoltClock! I didn't know you can't nest anchor tags in html5 and I didn't set the validator to html5 so this wasn't caught. Got it now, though!

Comment: Update: Pranav is right, it's nothing to do with the div, nested `a` tags aren't allowed

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate.

Comment: You ran it through a validator??  When I do I get lots of errors in HTML 4.01 (http://validator.w3.org/check) and errors about A tag nesting in html5 (http://html5.validator.nu/).  Which validator did you use?

Comment: @user1457366: Actually, I did not notice that extra nested `<a>` element. You can never nest `<a>` elements in any version of HTML, so I'm surprised that wasn't caught by whichever doctype you were validating against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have one `<a>` element inside another `<a>` element.  That's not allowed.  The browser is compensating by adding more `<a>` elements around the other link target content.

> **12.2.2 Nested links are illegal**
>
> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A element must not contain any other A elements.
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2

If you run it through an html5 validator it says so:

http://html5.validator.nu/

> Error: An a start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open.
>
> From line 14, column 5; to line 14, column 54
>
> `.</p>↩ <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">catego`